# Como pedir confirmacion en una ventana modal con yii2

Tags: modal, yii2

Lo que quiero hacer es, que al presionar un botón, le salga una ventana de confirmación al usuario, y en dependencia de su respuesta ejecuta o no la acción.

Para ello estoy usando una ventana modal con el widget Dialog de Kartik, que usa js para mostrar y obtener la respuesta del Dialogo, con este codigo:

```
// javascript for triggering the dialogs
$js = <<< JS
    $("#btn-borrafact").on("click", function() {
        krajeeDialog.confirm("¿Seguro que desea continuar?", function (result) {

            if (result) {
               // Aqui debe ir el codigo que llama a la accion del controlador
            } 
        });
    });
JS;
// register your javascript
$this->registerJs($js);
```

Lo que no se es, que poner para llamar a la accion que debe ejecutarse al responder que Si

O quizás tenga que usar otra forma de hacer lo que quiero.
De que forma podría hacer lo que necesito?

Answer (score 0):

Pues ya encontre la solucion, el codigo buscado es este:

```
window.location.href = '<nombre de la accion que quiero ejecutar>';
```